# ggplot2 not including each value on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data which I am trying to plot as a stacked area chart:

```
week    Wildtype    ARE
3       3770        3740
4       3910        3920
5       3660        3640
6       3750        3790
7       3940        3930
8       3940        3940
9       3830        3810
10      3710        3720
11      3730        3720
12      357         358
```

Using this code for a stacked area chart

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
rm(list=ls())
df <- read.csv("Mo_data/mo_qpcr_data2.csv", comment.char = "#", sep=",")
df_melt <- melt(df, id=c("week"))

p1 <- ggplot() + geom_area(aes(y = value, x = week, fill = variable), data = df_melt)
p1
```

I get the plot that I want but it isn't quite right. 
[image]

How do I change the plot so that the x-axis displays each week in the time series rather than just 5.0, 7.5 and 10.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add this to the code

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks= unique(df$week) ) 

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
rm(list=ls())
df <- read.csv("Mo_data/mo_qpcr_data2.csv", comment.char = "#", sep=",")
df_melt <- melt(df, id=c("week"))

p1 <- ggplot() + geom_area(aes(y = value, x = week, fill = variable), data = df_melt) + scale_x_continuous(breaks= unique(df$week) ) 
p1
```

Comment: Your're welcome. I would greatly appreciate your upvote on the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ggplot is treating your Week column as a number (rightly so, because it is a number), so your x axis appears as continuous. If you want to treat weeks as discrete values you can:

1) Change the week column to characters or factors

```
df_melt$week <- as.factor(df_melt$week)
df_melt$week <- as.factor(df_melt$week)
```

2) Tell the x axis where you want the breaks with `scale_axis_discrete` more info [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html)

Comment: ah, thanks a lot! Unfortunately though, if i do that it returns an empty graph with the correct labels?